# Image not upload if image name has numbers

Tags: php, image, upload, image-uploading

Hi I have this code below to upload/insert image and it's working fine. However, the images won't be upload/insert if the image name has numbers in it, **eg : IMG-20161225.png**

But when I upload/insert the image name **eg: image.png**, it uploads. Is there anything I need to change at my code? Thanks!

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
$date = date('y/m/d H:i:s');

function insertFile($filename,$date,$id){
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO upload (up_id, up_name,up_date,app_id) VALUES (NULL,'$filename','$date',last_insert_id())");
    if($sql){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

if(!isset($_FILES['filename'])){
    echo "";
}
else{

    $error=array();
    $extension=array("jpeg","jpg", "png");
    foreach($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name)
    {
        echo $file_name=$_FILES["filename"]["name"][$key];
        echo $file_tmp=$_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        echo $size=$_FILES["filename"]["size"][$key];
        $ext=pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(in_array($ext,$extension))
        {

                if(!file_exists("../upload/".$file_name)){
                    if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp=$_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"][$key], "../upload/".$file_name)){
                           //echo "Success on File Not Exist";
                         $insert = insertFile($file_name,$date,$id);
                           }
                            else{
                                echo mysql_error();
                            }
                }
                else
                    {
                        $filename=basename($file_name,$ext);
                        $newFileName=$filename.time().".".$ext;
                        if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp=$_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"][$key], "../upload/".$newFileName)){
                            $insert = insertFile($newFileName,$date,$id);
                            }
                        }
                    }
        }
```